# Chrome and jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, autocomplete

This is weird but I have some autocomplete code that I've customized to only engage when you type the '@' sign... In FireFox it works great. I type one '@' and the dropdown appears.

BUT... when I try it in Chrome, it requires two '@@' to engage the dropdown.

What could this be?

Here is the code in a switch statement that activates the autocomplete dropdown:

```
            case KEY.ATSIGN:
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(onChange, options.delay);
            //alert("hi");
            //select.show();
            break;
        default:

            break;
```

Another strange behavior is that when ad an alert statment, it actually works when I type one '@' in Chrome... Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

EDIT

Here's the onChange function where I am replacing the @ sign with blank "" so it doesn't show or submit the @ when an item is selected from the dropdown

```
    function onChange(crap, skipPrevCheck) {
    if( lastKeyPressCode == KEY.DEL ) {
        select.hide();
        return;
    }

    var currentValue = $input.val();

    if ( !skipPrevCheck && currentValue == previousValue )
        return;

    previousValue = currentValue;

    currentValue = lastWord(currentValue);
    if ( currentValue.length >= options.minChars) {
        $input.addClass(options.loadingClass);
        if (!options.matchCase)
            currentValue = currentValue.toLowerCase();
            currentValue = currentValue.replace("@","");
            request(currentValue, receiveData, hideResultsNow);
            //alert(currentValue);
    } else {
        stopLoading();
        select.hide();
    }
};
```

NEW EDIT
You can see the at sign ascii value is set here as 50

```
    var KEY = {
    UP: 38,
    DOWN: 40,
    DEL: 46,
    TAB: 9,
    RETURN: 13,
    ESC: 27,
    COMMA: 188,
    PAGEUP: 33,
    PAGEDOWN: 34,
    BACKSPACE: 8,
    ATSIGN: 50
};
```

Then in the switch statement, the autocomplete gets activated only when the @ sign is pressed:

```
        switch(event.keyCode) {

        case KEY.UP:
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( select.visible() ) {
                select.prev();
            } else {
                onChange(0, true);
            }
            break;

        case KEY.DOWN:
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( select.visible() ) {
                select.next();
            } else {
                onChange(0, true);
            }
            break;

        case KEY.PAGEUP:
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( select.visible() ) {
                select.pageUp();
            } else {
                onChange(0, true);
            }
            break;

        case KEY.PAGEDOWN:
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( select.visible() ) {
                select.pageDown();
            } else {
                onChange(0, true);
            }
            break;

        // matches also semicolon
        case options.multiple && $.trim(options.multipleSeparator) == "," && KEY.COMMA:
        case KEY.TAB:
        case KEY.RETURN:
            if( selectCurrent() ) {
                // stop default to prevent a form submit, Opera needs special handling
                event.preventDefault();
                blockSubmit = true;
                return false;
            }
            break;

        case KEY.ESC:
            select.hide();
            break;
        case KEY.ATSIGN:
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(onChange, options.delay);
            //alert("hi");
            //select.show();
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
```

And here is the function onChange that gets called in the case statement after @ is pressed

```
    function onChange(crap, skipPrevCheck) {
    if( lastKeyPressCode == KEY.DEL ) {
        select.hide();
        return;
    }

    var currentValue = $input.val();

    if ( !skipPrevCheck && currentValue == previousValue )
        return;

    previousValue = currentValue;
    //alert(previousValue);
    currentValue = lastWord(currentValue);
    if ( currentValue.length >= options.minChars) {
        $input.addClass(options.loadingClass);
        if (!options.matchCase)
            currentValue = currentValue.toLowerCase();
            currentValue = currentValue.replace("@","");
            //alert(currentValue);
            request(currentValue, receiveData, hideResultsNow);

    } else {
        stopLoading();
        select.hide();
    }
};
```

As I mentioned, this works great in FF... I press @ once and the autocomplete activates... However in Chrome, I must press @@ (at sign twice)....

Also here is a bit of code right before the switch statement

```
    // only opera doesn't trigger keydown multiple times while pressed, others don't work with keypress at all
$input.bind(($.browser.opera ? "keypress" : "keydown") + ".autocomplete", function(event) {
    // a keypress means the input has focus
    // avoids issue where input had focus before the autocomplete was applied
    hasFocus = 1;
    // track last key pressed
    lastKeyPressCode = event.keyCode;
```

Comment: To which event is the "activator" coupled? onkeyup?

Comment: I think you've just successfully showed us 2 pieces of code that have no relevance to the problem. :)

Comment: The activator is when you keypress the @ sign... Ascii 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the 3rd comment on the question.

[jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

you might want to try using keyup instead of keypress and see how far you get. Also, if you are posting a problem it's best to strip out all the non-relevant code and reduce your problem to the bare minimum.

you might also want to mock up a quick example at something like http://jsbin.com/

Comment: Well - I see you posted a duplicate of this question and then marked that you had found the answer - you should have done the same for this question - or asked for it to be closed...