# Capturing the tab key using JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, firefox, keypress

I use the following to restricts user to enter only some characters.
When I press tab, the cursor does not point to next control (in Mozilla). But it works fine in IE.

```
// Restricts user to enter characters other than a to z, A to Z and white space( )
// Rauf K. 06.11.2010
$("input:text.characters_only").keypress(function(e) {
if (!((e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) || e.which == 32 || e.which == 8 || e.which == 9)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend trying `e.keyCode` instead of `e.which`. Here is a SO link that describes a good method of getting the key strike into a single variable regardless: [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Comment: No, `keyCode` is the wrong property, because jQuery normalizes the `which` property. Most of the answers on the question you link to are hopelessly convoluted or misleading.

Comment: @Tim Down - I wasn't recommending all of the answers, just the accepted one.

Comment: @Tim: To repeat my comment from the other answer, as it really belongs here: I just tested this with Firefox using http://api.jquery.com/keypress : when I press <Tab>, `e.which` isn't set (remains `0`), but `e.keyCode` is (`9`).

Comment: @Marcel: Yes, fair point in this instance. In general, I would steer clear of using the `keyCode` property in a `keypress` handler: if you're interested in the physical key pressed use `keydown`, if you're interested in the character typed, use `keypress`.

Comment: @Tim: Indeed, but the OP wants to only allow certain key presses. If you want to catch that in a condition (and disallow everything else), you'll have to explicitly allow <Tab>, too. I can't think of another solution in this case.

Comment: which gives a 0 for escape also. Not sure why, maybe which is no good for non-characters?

Comment: @TimDown, correct. Essentially `null !== event.which ? event.which : null !== event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode ....` (+ same for mouse events..button 1,2,...)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps if you start with something like:

```
if (e.keyCode === 9) { // TAB
    return true;
}
```