# Make a if statement "fire" a key

Tags: java, if-statement, key

I was wondering how I could make an *if* statement:

```
if("up".equals(message))
{
     System.exit(0); //What I want to change
}
```

Act as if a key was pressed?

Like per-say I want this if statement to make it so that when 
*up* equals the message it will output a keypress like I pressed that key in the first place. I can't explain it too good but I hope this helps more

Just for anyone in the future
I used this

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    // Simulate a key press
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A); // press a
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A); // release a

} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks to Jdsfighter

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Can I suggest you flip the if to `if (message.equals("up"))`..trust me get in the habit of that if will save you one day

Comment: @Smitty Indeed. It could hide some possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are many many tuts, docos and q/as for catching key events, e.g. [How can I capture keyboard events are from which keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504914/how-can-i-capture-keyboard-events-are-from-which-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to physically press a key?

If so, the method to that is as follows:

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    // Simulate a key press
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A); // press a
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A); // release a

} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT: Revised**

In that case, here's a nice Oracle example on how to make a keylistener. From there you can use that information for whatever you need. [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: No I want to make it so that the if statements act as if it is a actual keypress

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to handle Input? 
To handle Input you need a KeyListener.

e.g:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class InputHandler implements KeyListener {

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("pressed "+e.getKeyChar());

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("released "+e.getKeyChar());

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("typed "+e.getKeyChar());

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.addKeyListener(new InputHandler());
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context is not really clear, but i think you looking for an implementation of KeyListener. Check the attached working example and see if it helps.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class KeyListenerExample implements KeyListener{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new KeyListenerExample().createFrame();
}

private void createFrame(){
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setSize(200, 300);
    jFrame.addKeyListener(this);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        System.out.println("UP arrow key pressed. Going to exit.");
         System.exit(0); //What I want to change
    }else{
        System.out.println("Some key pressed");
    }       
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {       
}
```

}