# Using event.which to verify if the user pressed the spacebar doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, keycode

I want a script to verify if the key pressed is 'spacebar', keycode 32. I noticed that IE uses other function names.

I tried a lot of solutions found here and this:

```
event = event || window.event // IE does not pass event to the function
if(event == window.event){
    code = event.keyCode;
}else{
    code = event.which;
} 
if(code == '32') {}
```

But it still didn't work in Firefox.

I think I'm calling the function wrongly in Firefox.  Look at the entire script:

```
<textarea onkeydown="predicao(this);" cols="40" rows="10" id="test" onfocus="this.focus()"></textarea>
<input id="example" style="display: none;" onkeydown="javascript: insert(this);"/>

<script language="Javascript">
<!--

function predicao(objeto){
    comprimento = objeto.value.length;
    var antipenultimo = comprimento - 4;
    var input = objeto.value.substring(antipenultimo,comprimento);
    var output = "";
    for(i=0; i<input.length; ++i){
        if(output != "") output += ", ";
        output += input.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    if (output == "91, 91, 103, 32"){

        var preditor = document.getElementById('example');
        preditor.value = '';
        preditor.style.display = 'block';
        preditor.focus();
        preditor.select();
    }  
}
function insert(objeto){
event = event.which || window.event // IE does not pass event to the function
if(event == window.event){
    code = event.keyCode;
}else{
    code = event.charCode;
} 
    if(keynum == '32') {
        var texto = document.getElementById('test').value;
        texto += objeto.value+']]';
        $('#test').focus();
        document.getElementById('test').value = texto;
        objeto.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = "Ab Aco Ado Ala Mano Cata Ca Obo Olo Po Poq".split(" ");
$("#example").autocomplete(data);});
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is - (I don't know the name) - a Prediction Help Inputter inside a textarea. It uses jQuery autocomplete. 
When the user types '[[g ' inside textarea (id=test), a input with autocomplete is opened (id=example), so it search in 'data'. When the user find the desired data, he must press spacebar to insert the data into the textarea, closing with ']]' But it doesn't work in Firefox.

(And yes, I'm using JavaScript and jQuery to same elements in a totally wrong way because I'm not too good at this, I'll try to correct it after Firefox works.)

Comment: show the complete function. You MUST pass event as function whatever(event) for fx to work - also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed

Comment: No need for the javascript: either onkeydown="javascript: <<<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

HMTL:

```
<textarea onkeydown="predicao(this);" cols="40" rows="10" id="test" onfocus="this.focus()"></textarea>
<input id="example" style="display: none;" onkeydown="insert(this, event);"/>
```

JS:

```
function predicao(objeto){
    var comprimento = objeto.value.length;
    var antipenultimo = comprimento - 4;
    var input = objeto.value.substring(antipenultimo,comprimento);
    var output = "";
    for(var i=0; i<input.length; ++i){
        if(output != "") output += ", ";
        output += input.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    if (output == "91, 91, 103, 32"){
        var preditor = document.getElementById('example');
        preditor.value = '';
        preditor.style.display = 'block';
        preditor.focus();
        preditor.select();
    }
}
function insert(objeto, evt){
    var e = evt || event;
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == '32') {
        var texto = document.getElementById('test').value;
        texto += objeto.value+']]';
        $('#test').focus();
        document.getElementById('test').value = texto;
        objeto.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = "Ab Aco Ado Ala Mano Cata Ca Obo Olo Po Poq".split(" ");
$("#example").autocomplete(data);});
```

I used here what Alexander Kahoun and pimvdb have posted.

Comment: It works in Chrome, but I think I'm calling it wrong in FF. This all my code:

Comment: It might be a good idea to declare `code` with `var` though. You can also do `var code = e.keyCode || e.which`. :)

Comment: @user893149 - It works for me on Opera 11.50, Firefox 5 and Google Chrome 13. Your code has been cut off (in your comment).

Comment: You need a var on e and code.  Without them you are making them global and they can interfere with other scripts.

Comment: I was insertin 'event' inside the function, I think it was that wrong

Comment: @Leo - Other problems was this line `if(keynum == '32')` , no `event` here `onkeydown="insert(this);"` , no semicolon at the end of one line...

Comment: lol, I thought I could accept all! I tryed all and all worked. I would like to be grateful to all of you! Thanks for semicolon tip too!

Comment: You can accept only one answer but you can upvote every answer. Just click o arrow up on the top left corner of answer. For accept someone will get 15 points and for upvote 10 points.

Answer (score 3):

I've never had any problems with the following and I've used it in IE6 through IE9, Firefox 3.5-5 and Chrome from at least 9-13

```
function captureSpace (evt) {
    var e = evt || event;
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 32) {
        // Do your thing...
    }
}
```

---

This uses a logical OR to basically say if `evt` is a falsy value then use the `window.event`

```
var e = evt || event;
```

---

This uses a logical OR to assign the code for the key pressed in the same way

```
var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

---

This gives you a true or false value if the code is exactly equal to the integer value of 32

```
(code === 32)
```

---

I also suggest that you assign this to the key UP event.

Comment: `var e = evt || event;` to `var e = evt || window.event;` ?

Comment: event is shorthand for window.event.  Try out this jsfiddle in IE to see: http://jsfiddle.net/arcond/yVXy4/

Comment: this function have no name, how i should call this?

Answer (score 0):

In principle the way you do it should work. Check this out:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(e){
 var keynum
 if(window.event)
 {
  keynum = e.keyCode
 }
 else if(e.which)
 {
  keynum = e.which
 }
 if(keynum=='32')
 {
  alert(keynum);}
  }
</script>
</head>
<form>
<input type="text" onkeypress="check(event)" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that your lack of response is context dependent.

Comment: Several problems there. `if(window.event) { keynum = event.keyCode }`
and `if (keynum==32)`

Comment: I think you are right, i think I calling the function wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

To display unicode of key pressed

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
                function displayunicode(e){
                                            var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
                                            alert(unicode);
                                          }
        </script>
                <form>
                      <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" onkeyup="displayunicode(event); this.select()" />
                </form>
```

[Determining which key was pressed](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey2.shtml)