# Space bar keyCode(32) not working on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, space, keycode, onkeypress

Enter `keyCode(13)` works fine on all browsers.

Space bar `keyCode(32)` I tested on Chrome works fine but not responding on Firefox. I used the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function enterPressed(evn) {
        var e_id = $('e_id').value;
        var e_fname = $('e_fname').value;
        var e_role = $('e_role').value;

        if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13) {
            Monitor.Order.assign(e_id, e_fname, e_role);
        } else if (evn && evn.keyCode == 13) {
            Monitor.Order.assign(e_id, e_fname, e_role);
        } else if (evn && evn.keyCode == 32) {
            Monitor.Order.updateStatus('COOKED');
        }                       
    }
    document.onkeypress = enterPressed;     
</script>
```

Why is this not working in Firefox when it works in Chrome?

Comment: have you tried with. `evn = evn || window.event` ?

Comment: Check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051112/event-which-doesnt-workin-in-firefox

Comment: No but I don't know how ?

Comment: A quick fix would be to use `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress`, it seems, that FF doesn't trigger `keypress` when space is hit. An example: http://jsfiddle.net/8EFhW/0

Comment: I tried the fiddle works fine and I just tested with simple alert('TEST'); instead of updateStatus() but still not working

Comment: Thank you it works with onkeyup.

Comment: It seems my explanation why FF fails with this was wrong. `keypress` is fired when hitting `space`, but the `keyCode` is `0` rather than `32`, though `which` returns correct value...

Answer (score 5):

Space is a printable character, so the keypress event will have the `charCode` set to the character that it corresponds to and the `keyCode` won't be set on the keypress event in Firefox.

In general, you want to use `charCode` for printable things in keypress, `keyCode` in keyup/keydown.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will work fine ....

```
function enterPressed(evn) {
if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for Firefox/x.x or Firefox x.x 

        var e_id = $('e_id').value;
        var e_fname = $('e_fname').value;
        var e_role = $('e_role').value;

        if (evn.which == 13) {
            Monitor.Order.assign(e_id, e_fname, e_role);
        } else if (evn.which == 13) {
            Monitor.Order.assign(e_id, e_fname, e_role);
        } else if (evn.which == 32) {
            Monitor.Order.updateStatus('COOKED');
        }                
    }

     else{
            var e_id = $('e_id').value;
            var e_fname =$('e_fname').value;
            var e_role = $('e_role').value;

            if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13) {
                Monitor.Order.assign(e_id, e_fname, e_role);
            } else if (evn && evn.keyCode == 13) {
               Monitor.Order.assign(e_id, e_fname, e_role);
            } else if (evn && evn.keyCode == 32) {
                Monitor.Order.updateStatus('COOKED');
            }  

        }
    }
    document.onkeypress = enterPressed;
```