# What Javascript event is fired when "return" is clicked on an iPad when an input is selected?

Tags: javascript, forms, ipad, safari, jquery-events

Which Javascript event is fired when someone presses the "return" key on an iPad in Safari while an input is selected.

I'm using an input element, but not surrounding it in `<form>` tags. I submit the `$('#input').value()` when `$('#button').click()` occurs. However, I'd like to also like to be able to submit when someone presses "return" on the iPad keyboard.

I was overzealous, here is the answer:

[jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Comment: I was overzealous:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a `<form>` tag and binding your handler to the `submit` tag.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
   doStuff();
});
```

It's cleaner and simpler.

Comment: probably going to end up doing this, but if you were curious for how to do it based on the keycode check the link i posted. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can detect the enter key event in safari on ipad with following way :

```
<body onkeyup="yourFunction(event)">
```

then in javaScript

```
function yourFunction(event) {
    var e;
    if(event) {
        e = event;
    } else {
        e = window.event;
    }

    if(e.which){
       var keycode = e.which;
    } else {
       var keycode = e.keyCode;
    } 

    if(keycode == 13) {
       alert("do your stuff");
    }
};
```