# jQuery not detecting enter key pressed in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

My setup: jQuery 1.6.2

I have this HTML

```
<textarea class="comment_box"> Write a comment...</textarea>
```

And the following Javascript

```
<script>
$('.comment_box').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        alert('you pressed enter ^_^');
    }
})
</script>
```

When I press the enter key in the textarea, nothing triggers

**EDIT** Oops, cut and paste error, I do have `$` in my code and it still doesn't work, must be something else going on.

My bad, it is a user operator error, it does work. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Guess is a type when you past code here. But `('.comment_box')` shouldn't be `$('.comment_box')`?

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.comment_box').keypress(function(event) {
    // Check the keyCode and if the user pressed Enter (code = 13) 
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('you pressed enter ^_^');
    }
});
```

Thats it

Answer (score 2):

Check out this answer:

[jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed/302161#302161)

> ```
> var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
>  if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
>    //Do something
>  }
> ```

Comment: There's no need for that. jQuery normalizes the `which` property.

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery you need to use the $ to specify.

```
$('.comment_box').keyd
```

should do it.