# event.keycode not returning correct values in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keypress, keycode

I am trying the following code for triggering a js method when `space-bar` is pressed within an input box.

```
  <input id="j1" /> 

  $('#j1').keypress (function (event){
       alert(event.keycode)
  });
```

In firefox this returns correct value only when `enter` is pressed, values returned for other keys are just **0** everytime. In IE/ chrome this works perfectly.

Answer (score 29):

In non-IE browsers, you want the `which` or `charCode` property in a `keypress` event rather than the `keyCode` property. The `keypress` event is for detecting typed characters while `keyup` and `keydown` are for detcting physical keys (in those events, `keyCode` works in every major browser).

```
var charCode = (typeof event.which == "number") ? event.which : event.keyCode;
```

However, jQuery normalizes the `which` property of keypress events by using code similar to this, so in jQuery you just need

```
var charCode = event.which;
```

For (a lot) more detail about key events, see http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is not all browsers have the same implementations on keypresses. The solution would be to check all possible places where the `key` was registered. In this case: `event.keycode` and `event.which`

See this post for more info

[jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

**EDIT**

Finally dug up my old functions, this is the actual code that I use:

```
evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
var charCode = evt.which || evt.charCode || evt.keyCode || 0;
```

Comment: this returns undefined for `enter` in firefox

Comment: yes, but the OP is trying to catch the `spacebar` keypress =)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually typed that on the fly =) The edited version should work

Comment: `evt.which || evt.charCode || evt.keyCode || 0` - 50% less space

Comment: @SomeGuy, this will return a boolean value right? Then charCode will have a boolean value instead of anyone of the three above. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Rolando: No, the `||` does not necessarily evaluate to a Boolean value. `a || b` evaluates to `a` if `a` is truthy and `b` otherwise.

Comment: @Rolando, @SomeGuy: Also, there's no need to use `charCode` at all. Every browser that supports `charCode` also supports `which`, and some (Opera) only support `which`.

Answer (score 2):

IF **`event.keyCode`** is not returning proper values then for firefox you can use **`event.charCode`**

```
var keyValue = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
```

Answer (score 2):

### KeyboardEvent.keyCode :

> The value of keypress event is different between browsers. IE and
>   Google Chrome set the KeyboardEvent.charCode value. Gecko sets 0 if
>   the pressed key is a printable key, otherwise it sets the same keyCode
>   as a keydown or keyup event

So from Firefox point of view, it has actually returned correct values. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

`keyCode`, `which`, `keyIdentifier` and `charCode` are deprecated

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being 
>   dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible;

`keyIdentifier` had no support in IE and Firefox and been dropped from Opera and Chrome
*With* `charCode` as Non-standard

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations

So what are the alternatives?

### I. Use the `key` property instead

```
readonly attribute DOMString key
```

> Holds a key attribute value corresponding to the key pressed

Examples :
"a", "A", "@", "%", "$",  "ا", "ب", "ة", "ت", ..., "١", "٢", "٣", "Tab", "Enter" , all "F1"...`

It has earned the support of all major browsers (Firefox 52, Chrome 55, Safari 10.1, Opera 46) except Internet Explorer 11 which has 
non-standard key identifiers and incorrect behavior with AltGraph. [More info](http://caniuse.com/#search=.key)
                 If that is important and/or backward compatibility is, then you can use feature detection as in the following code :

*Notice that the `key`value is different from `keyCode` or `which` properties in that : it contains the name of the key not its code. If your program needs characters' codes then you can make use of `charCodeAt()`.
For single printable characters you can use `charCodeAt()`, if you're dealing with keys whose values contains multiple characters like <kbd>ArrowUp</kbd>
chances are : you are testing for special keys and take actions accordingly. So try implementing a table of keys' values and their corresponding
            codes `charCodeArr["ArrowUp"]=38`, `charCodeArr["Enter"]=13`,`charCodeArr[Escape]=27`... and so on, please take a look at [Key Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) and their [corresponding codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025(v=vs.60).aspx)*

```
if(e.key!=undefined){
        var characterCode = charCodeArr[e.key] || e.key.charCodeAt(0);
    }else{
        /* As @Leonid suggeted   */
        var characterCode = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    }
        /* ... code making use of characterCode variable  */
```

### II.You can also use the `code` property :

```
readonly attribute DOMString code
```

> Holds a string that identifies the physical key being pressed. The
>   value is not affected by the current keyboard layout or modifier
>   state, so a particular key will always return the same value.

It has a similar effect to the `key` property and an output like `"keyW"` for button W pressed of a US keyboard with QUERTY 
layout. If the same button was pressed in another layout (AZERTY) or another language (Hebrew) or combined with a modifier 
(shift), `key` property would change accordingly, while the `code` property would still have the same value `"keyW"`
more on this [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/keyboardevent-keys-codes).

The `code` property is supported in Chrome 49, Firefox 52, Safari 10.1 and Opera 46 But not in Internet Explorer.

see also :

1. [KeyboardEvent.charCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode)
2. [KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyIdentifier)
3. [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)
4. [KeyboardEvent.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which)
5. [KeyboardEvent.key](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#dom-keyboardevent-key)
6. [key property support](http://caniuse.com/#search=.key)
7. [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)
8. [code property support](http://caniuse.com/#search=KeyboardEvent.code)

Answer (score 1):

if you're getting a `0` no matter which key you press, try using `charCode` instead of `keyCode`

This happens because you are calling the KeyboardEvent object which uses `which` and `charCode` as opposed to the Event object which uses `keyCode` for returning keyboard Unicode values. For more information, refer to MDN web docs for more information regarding the KeyboardEvent:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent