# KeyboardEvent.keyCode deprecated. What does this mean in practice?

Tags: javascript, key, deprecated, keycode

According to MDN, we should most definitely **not** be using the `.keyCode` property. It is deprecated:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

On W3 school, this fact is played down and there is only a side note saying that `.keyCode` is provided for compatibility only and that the latest version of the DOM Events Specification recommend using the `.key` property instead.

The problem is that `.key` is not supported by browsers, so what should we using? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `.key` is supported in every major browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#Browser_compatibility

Comment: This question doesn't seem particularly useful anymore since all modern browsers support `event.key`.

Comment: Currently 2023. The strange thing is that sometimes `.key` has the value `Unidentified`, this time we need `keyCode`. 

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You have three ways to handle it, as it's written on the link you shared.

```js
if (event.key !== undefined) {

} else if (event.keyIdentifier !== undefined) {

} else if (event.keyCode !== undefined) {

}
```

you should contemplate them, that's the right way if you want cross browser support.

It could be easier if you implement something like this.

```js
var dispatchForCode = function(event, callback) {
  var code;

  if (event.key !== undefined) {
    code = event.key;
  } else if (event.keyIdentifier !== undefined) {
    code = event.keyIdentifier;
  } else if (event.keyCode !== undefined) {
    code = event.keyCode;
  }

  callback(code);
};
```

Comment: I did read that that but it seemed to be a lot of extra code for no other reason than MDN have said something is deprecated, when it actually works fine in all major browsers. But if that's the correct way then thanks!

Comment: Wow look a this. http://caniuse.com/#search=keyCode (This KeyboardEvent property is supported in effectively all browsers (since IE6+, Firefox 2+, Chrome 1+ etc "talking about .keyCode)

Comment: That's what is so annoying about all this. All major browsers support keyCode, but try do a check for the .key property, which is the recommended one, and hardly any use it!

Comment: Yeah, we're up to late May 2016, and chrome finally implemented the KeyboardEvent.key property. Safari along with every mobile browser has yet to join the "16.5% of all users" party. Also, sadly, Microsoft Edge and Gecko encode quite a few of the events differently for example: the key event for the up arrow is encoded as "Up" instead of "ArrowUp".

Comment: I think this will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465542/angular2-input-field-to-accept-only-numbers

Comment: But `event.key` is a string, whereas `event.keyCode` is a number, right? Given that they don't even have the same type, have can they have the same semantics? Or do you mean `event.code`?

Comment: As of now, all major browsers support `event.key` and `event.code` (check @kumarharsh's answer). It being a `string` also makes it a lot more readable, so I advise using it for all new code. For maintaining legacy, it will depend on how much you depend on it being a `number`. Just be aware that when you hit a printable key, `event.key` "a" and "A" are different while `event.code` will be "keyA" for both. For non printable, you can have `event.code` being "ShiftLeft" or "ShiftRight" while `event.key` will be "Shift" for both.

Comment: What is the benefit of using a callback for this function?

Comment: @GuilhermeTaffarelBergamin Sorry to burst your bubble but Chrome on Android still doesn't support event.code (as of June 2021). But I agree that the way to go is probably to use those (code and key) and to import a polyfill. Making things cross browser should not be mingled with your business code.

Comment: @pieroxy. I should probably test that again then to be sure, because [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), `event.code` became available on Chrome for Android on version 48 with full support. But now that you mention it, [according to caniuse](https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-code), it is only supported if turned it on as an experimental feature flag.

Answer (score 261):

For instance if you want to detect whether the "Enter"-key was clicked or not:

Instead of

```js
event.keyCode === 13
```

Do it like

```js
event.key === 'Enter'
```

Comment: In the light of the "in practice" part of the question, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: For non-ASCII composing letters, the key event fires twice. Each are { key: 'Enter', keyCode: 13 }, { key: 'Enter', keyCode: 229 }. How can I avoid second event without keyCode?

Comment: @khcpietro Can’t really reproduce that with `Enter`, but there’s an [`isComposing`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/isComposing) property and two related events that may help.

Comment: The list of all possible values of event.key: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values

Comment: `event.keyCode === 27` become: `event.key === 'Escape'`

Comment: keep in mind that changing from `event.keyCode === 13` to `event.key === 'Enter'` drops support for numpad keys. To support both, check both:

`event.key === 'Enter' || event.key === 'NumpadEnter'`

or better yet:

`['Enter', 'NumpadEnter'].includes(event.key)`

Comment: 2 cents for the shortest code / widest test: `/enter/i.test(key)`

Comment: @AustinArnett `.key==="Enter"` for both keys. But `.code` can also be "NumpadEnter".

Answer (score 51):

TLDR: I'd suggest that you **should** use the new `event.key` and `event.code` properties instead of the legacy ones. IE and Edge have support for these properties, but don't support the new key names yet. For them, there is a small polyfill which makes them output the standard key/code names:

https://github.com/shvaikalesh/shim-keyboard-event-key

---

I came to this question searching for the reason of the same MDN warning as OP. After searching some more, the issue with `keyCode` becomes more clear:

The problem with using `keyCode` is that non-English keyboards can produce different outputs and even keyboards with different layouts can produce inconsistent results. Plus, there was the case of

If you read the W3C spec:
https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#interface-keyboardevent

> In practice, keyCode and charCode are **inconsistent** across platforms and even the same implementation on different operating systems or using different localizations.

It goes into some depth describing what was wrong with `keyCode`:
https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#legacy-key-attributes

> These features were never formally specified and the current browser implementations vary in significant ways. The large amount of legacy content, including script libraries, that relies upon detecting the user agent and acting accordingly means that any attempt to formalize these legacy attributes and events would risk breaking as much content as it would fix or enable. Additionally, **these attributes are not suitable for international usage, nor do they address accessibility concerns.**

So, after establishing the reason why the legacy keyCode was replaced, let's look at what you need to do today:

1. All modern browsers support the new properties (`key` and `code`).
2. IE and Edge support an older version of the spec, which has different names for some keys. You can use a shim for it: https://github.com/shvaikalesh/shim-keyboard-event-key (or roll your own - it's rather small anyways)
3. Edge has fixed this bug in the latest release (probably will be released in Apr 2018) - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8860571/
4. Refer to the list of event keys you can use: https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/

Comment: [**According to the MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), neither Internet Explorer nor Edge support `KeyboardEvent.code`. Also, the values for `key` and `code` are browser dependent. Both issues making `key` and `code` not practical to use in real life applications.

Comment: @JohnSlegers please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: If I want to test the arrow keys, page up/down, home & end, should I use `key` or `code`?  It's generally a physical key, but can depend on Num Lock and layout too...  What's the best practice?

Comment: It being a `string` also makes it a lot more readable, so it is advisable to use it for all new code. For maintaining legacy, it will depend on how much you depend on it being a `number`. Just be aware that when you hit a printable key, `event.key` "a" and "A" are different while `event.code` will be "keyA" for both. For non printable, you can have `event.code` being "ShiftLeft" or "ShiftRight" while `event.key` will be "Shift" for both.

Answer (score 33):

In addition that all of [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which), [charCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode) and [keyIdentifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyIdentifier) are deprecated :
`charCode` and `keyIdentifier` are non-standard features.
`keyIdentifier` is removed as of Chrome 54 and Opera 41.0
`keyCode` returns 0, on keypress event with normal characters on FF.

[The key property](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#dom-keyboardevent-key) :

```
 readonly attribute DOMString key
```

> Holds a key attribute value corresponding to the key pressed

As of the time of this writing, the `key` property is supported by all major browsers as of : Firefox 52, Chrome 55, Safari 10.1, Opera 46. Except Internet Explorer 11 which has :
*non-standard key identifiers and incorrect behavior with AltGraph. [More info](http://caniuse.com/#search=.key)*
                 If that is important and/or backward compatibility is, then you can use feature detection as in the following code :

*Notice that the `key`value is different from `keyCode` or `which` properties in that : it contains the name of the key not its code. If your program needs characters' codes then you can make use of `charCodeAt()`.
For single printable characters you can use `charCodeAt()`, if you're dealing with keys whose values contains multiple characters like <kbd>ArrowUp</kbd>
chances are : you are testing for special keys and take actions accordingly. So try implementing a table of keys' values and their corresponding
            codes `charCodeArr["ArrowUp"]=38`, `charCodeArr["Enter"]=13`,`charCodeArr[Escape]=27`... and so on, please take a look at [Key Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) and their [corresponding codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025(v=vs.60).aspx)*

```
if(e.key!=undefined){
        var characterCode = charCodeArr[e.key] || e.key.charCodeAt(0);
    }else{
        /* As @Leonid suggeted   */
        var characterCode = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    }
        /* ... code making use of characterCode variable  */
```

May be you want to consider forward compatibility i.e use the legacy properties while they're available, and only when dropped switch to the new ones :

```
if(e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode ){
        var characterCode = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    }else if (e.key!=undefined){
        var characterCode = charCodeArr[e.key] || e.key.charCodeAt(0);
    }else{
        var characterCode = 0;
    }
```

See also : the `KeyboardEvent.code` property [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) and some more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330724/event-keycode-not-returning-correct-values-in-firefox/45771014#45771014).

Comment: You solution doesn't work in my browser (Windows 10, Chrome 60, Belgian keyboard). First of all, the `charCodeArr` function does not exist. Also, `charCodeAt` doesn't work for all values of `e.key`. For example, for the `Enter` /  `Return` key, the value of `e.key` property is `"Enter"`, and executing `charCodeArr` for that string returns the value `69` (which is the ASCII code for the character `E`).

Comment: @JohnSlegers, yes that was a typo, I meant a user built array. Please, see my updated answer for more details.

Answer (score 18):

MDN has already provided a solution:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) {
    return; // Should do nothing if the default action has been cancelled
  }

  var handled = false;
  if (event.key !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.key and set handled true.
  } else if (event.keyIdentifier !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier and set handled true.
  } else if (event.keyCode !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.keyCode and set handled true.
  }

  if (handled) {
    // Suppress "double action" if event handled
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}, true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `key` is a browser-specific string value like `"Enter"` or `"ArrowUp"` and there's no standardized way to convert it to the corresponding code. so you're going to need even more boilerplate code to convert between key & code.

Answer (score 7):

`e.charCode` has been deprecated:

```
<input
  onChange={(e) => setToken(e.target.value)}
  type="text"
  value={token}
  onKeyPress={(e) => {
    if (e.charCode === 13) {
      verifyLoginF()
    }
  }}
/>
```

[image]

you should use now:`e.key === 'Enter'`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here was proposed to use **key** value instead of **keyCode** and if it fails then use **keyCode**. Though this is not enough, because values in this attributes are not compatible. Thing is new **key** contains the string for control keys, like: ArrowUp, but **keyCode** will contain just code which with trivial

```
String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)
```

will result in a non-printable char. Here the solution for printable chars:

```
element.keydown((event) => {
    var symbolPressed;
    //cross browser
    if (event.key !== undefined) {
        symbolPressed = event.key; //Here control characters represented as String like: ArrowUp
        if (symbolPressed.length > 1) return; //filter out control characters
    } else if (event.keyCode !== undefined) {
        symbolPressed = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); //Here control chars represented as one char string
    }
    //Update this regex if you need other characters
    if (!symbolPressed.match(/[A-z0-9\s]/)) return;
    console.log(symbolPressed);
});
```

And in case of you need non-printable control characters, you have to update conditions and regex accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Using onkeypress and onkeydown to event.which, it
is switch [CHARACTER code] or [KEYcode]

```js
 function myKey(event){
 
  var keycode = event.keyCode;  //key code variant 1, not recomendate
  var keywhic = event.which;    //key code variant 2, nice worked 
  var unicode = event.key;      //string name code, nice worked  
  var chacode = event.charCode; //works onkeypress="myKey(event)"
  var metakey = event.metaKey;  //true false, winKey or macComand
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = keycode+" "+keywhic+" "+unicode+" "+chacode+" "+metakey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onkeydown="myKey(event)"> <!--onkeypress="myKey(event)"-->

<h1 id="demo">Keyboard Buttons click me and test the keyboard</h1>
<script>
 //function myKey(event){
 //paste code
 //}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use

```
parseInt(event.key, radix: 10)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes