# In a KeyboardEvent, which property should be used to determine which key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

e.g. A keypress event will return the below

```
KeyboardEvent {
    charCode: 32,
    code: "Space",
    key: " ", // space character
    keyCode: 32,
    which: 32
}
```

Which (if any) of these are deprecated/should not be used? Code makes sense to me because it's human readable. Afaik, `which` is deprecated.

Comment: `key` gives `c` and `C` respectively when shift is (not) pressed, while `code` returns `KeyC` for both cases. Furthermore, this ignores the user's keyboard layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did some research... According to mdn (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) we should use `key` "If available".

`char` is deprecated

`charCode` is deprecated

`keyCode` is deprecated

`which` is deprecated

`code` is not deprecated, so I assume we use this if `key` is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking in the debugger and tracing out an event object in Angular 2. You would clearly use keyCode. I'm pretty sure that's what the docs say too. Interested where this conversation goes. However note I use keyCode and get exactly what I need from all keys (enter shift etc).

It makes sense I guess; you want the key, use the keycode. You want the character, use charCode. You might intuit them as the same but it would seem they're not (or at least, not always).

Just to add all the detail, I'm bound to the keyup event. It's probably not angular 2 specific but just sharing environment etc.

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated and should not be used (wherever possible).

Comment: Can you show some documentation to that effect (that is not easily refuted)? Looking at the info in the debugger, charCode wouldn't be useful. I see a reference to MDN saying deprecated, but I also see W3C that event.key is not universally supported. The angular docs frequently mention keyCode. Another stackoverflow answer says there's key, keyCode and keyIdentifier. But again, when passing in the event, the only consistently useful thing seems to be keyCode. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394937/javascript-keycode-deprecated-what-does-this-mean-in-practice

Comment: Anyway, with all that said, I looked around and couldn't establish the deprecation as a practical and consistent fact. (Note the point here is to find out the useful practice for day-to-day dev, not to say you're wrong).

Answer (score 0):

`keyCode` determine which key is pressed.except `keyCode` includes `shiftKey`,`altKey`,`ctrlKey`,`metaKey` to detect special keys.

Comment: Interestingly, keyCode is what I use in Angular 2. I don't see charcode on the incoming event.

Comment: they are the same.so you must use `var key = e.charCode | e.keyCode `

Comment: Actually I rectract that. charCode would be the entered character. Keycode is the key pressed. They are not the same (looking in debugger right now). For example, I see charCode 0, keyCode 62. I would say keyCode is correct for knowing the key (for some reason I think I knew this already). I mean, it does kind of make sense if you think about it.

Comment: yes,diff property for diff lowest version browsers.but now they are both could used in many browsers.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't seeing charcode because I was doing a naive falsy check. The value is 0, so I "didn't see it".