# Is there a way to detect if the enter key is pressed while in an input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a search bar that needs to detect if the enter key is pressed but I can't seem to find a working option. A little of my code:

```
<div class="searchbar">
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
```

I tried

```
let input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {   
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {   
        console.log(e.target.value);   
    }   
})
```

but keyCode is deprecated. Any advice?

Comment: @Santrix refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394937/keyboardevent-keycode-deprecated-what-does-this-mean-in-practice)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `e.keycode === 13` you can use `e.key === 'Enter'`