# Keydown in jquery - Can I target specific letters with any kind of plugin?

Tags: jquery, keydown

I need to call a function when a certain letter is pressed, i.e. pressing 'l' changes a div's class, and pressing 'g' changes it to another class.

Can this be done natively in jquery, or will I have to find a plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: One of my favorites: http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Comment: I'd refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.which == 39) { 
       rightArrowFunction();
   }
});
```

Comment: jQuery normalizes which for keyCode and charCode so it's already cross-browser good

Comment: Thanks kinakuta! That makes sense, now that you mention it.