# Is there a way to animate the opacity of textarea with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-events

I need to animate the opacity of the text in textarea, so it fades away.This happens when someone presses enter. I have setup the code for the enter press, but can't get the code to animate to work.
Here is the code I have:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if(e.which === 13){
// here I would like to animate the text
   };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For only the text, I would think you would need jQueryUI, and do something like this:

```
$("#textarea").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
        $(this).animate({color: 'transparent'},1000);
   }
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7pkNK/

Be aware that the cursor will disappear as well, and as far as I know the only way around it is to create a cursor with an animated gif or some other custom code.

Comment: Thanks, the cursor disappearing is perfect for my case.It fits what i need to do.Thank you very much.

Comment: @suludi You should accept this as the answer if it was a solution for you.

Comment: Also please, do i need to add the whole jQuery UI, or i can only add rhe effects stripped part.

Comment: You would only need the UI Effects core to animate colors.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
     if(e.which === 13){
      $(formelement).animate({ color: "#FFFFFF" }, 600);

   };
});
```

Comment: This fades the whole textarea, i just want to fade the text.

Answer (score 0):

Would this example from the JQuery API help?

```
<div id="clickme">
   Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" />

$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Check out the API for .fadeIn() and .fadeTo() as well.

In your case, you could just use $('#text' ).fadeOut();

Comment: Thanks, i now what FadeOut does, but i need to fade the text away, not the whole textarea.

Comment: @suludi If you wrap text in a <span> or <p> tag, you can do something like: `$('#textarea span').fadeOut()`. This will fade only the text.

Comment: That's not possible, you can't wrap the text in a textarea in HTML elements.

Comment: @suludi you can also assign the text an ID `<span id="text"></span>` then... `$('#text').fadeOut();

Comment: @adeneo Sorry I misspoke. I specified another element like a <div> with the ID of "textarea". Not the HTML element <textarea>.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it using [jQuery's fadeOut method](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code === 13) {
        //here i would like to animate the text
        $('#idofobject').fadeOut(optionalduration, optionalcallback);
    }
});
```

I'd retrieve the key being pressed using the second line of my code, as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/302161/435460).

---

After reading your comment to @dremme, I don't believe there's a way to fade *just the text* that is simple.  You'd have to place a div over top of your textarea with the text in it, delete the text that is currently in the textarea, and fadeout your covering div.