# why jQuery e.which does not work to detect input key?

Tags: jquery, input, keycode

I have a simple HTML like this:

```
Get alert with inserting a + sign: <input type="text" class="data" />
```

I want alert user whenever he/she press **+** key. But my jQuery code does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".data").bind('keydown',function(e){
        if(e.which == 107){
            alert('Plus sign entered');
        });
    });
});
```

What do I have to do ?

(This is [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K33hm/2/))

Comment: try using keyup instead of keydown. also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two things wrong in this code.

1. There was a typo(?) - closing curly braces for the IF condition
2. The key ID for SHIFT and = (which is +) is different from the numpad +

The following code fixes it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".data").bind('keydown',function(e){

        if(e.which == 107 || e.which == 187){
            alert('Plus sign entered');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/DgUUB/