# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Google Chrome is throwing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isDown' of undefined" but it doesn't look like anything is wrong with my code!

Important part of my variable array:

```
KEY = {
    UP: 38,
    DOWN: 40,
    W: 87,
    S: 83,
    D: 68
}
pingpong = {
    fps: 60,
    pressedKeys: [],
    complete: false,
}
```

Key listener initialization (this is where the error is thrown):

```
    for (var keyCode in KEY) {
        if (KEY.hasOwnProperty(keyCode)) {
            pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY[keyCode]] = {
                isDown: false,
                wasDown: false
            };
        }
    }
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        pingpong.pressedKeys[e.which].isDown = true;
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
/* This line is the issue */    pingpong.pressedKeys[e.which].isDown = false;
    });
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What button do you press when the issue occurs? Perhaps this button is not described in KEY object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access an element of the `pressedKeys` array which does not exist. For example, if we pressed the "a" key:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    //Pressed "a" so e.which == 65
    pingpong.pressedKeys[e.which].isDown = false;
});
```

When you initialize your array you only create elements for the properties of the `KEY` object:

```
for (var keyCode in KEY) {
    //Iterating over KEY, which contains 5 properties...
    if (KEY.hasOwnProperty(keyCode)) {
        //Add value to pressedKeys (this happens for each of the 5 properties)
        pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY[keyCode]] = {
            isDown: false,
            wasDown: false
        };
    }
}
```

So `pressedKeys` only contains 5 elements, corresponding to the properties of `KEY`. Note that a TypeError is also thrown in the `keydown` event handler, as well as `keyup`.

To fix it, you could check that `e.which` is in the `KEYS` object in the event handler functions. If it's not, just ignore it. Something like this perhaps (there may be a better way, this is just what came to mind first):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    for(var k in KEY) {
        if(KEY[k] == e.which) {
            break; //Break out of loop and execute last line
        }
        return false; //Key not recognized, last line is not executed
    }
    pingpong.pressedKeys[e.which].isDown = true;
});
```

Comment: So what do you propose as my solution?

Comment: If I understand correctly, its checking if the input is in KEY, if so, carry on normally, if not, don't add it to pressedKeys.

Comment: That's right. It checks whether `e.which` (which is the pressed key code) is in the `KEY` object. If it is, the `break` statement is reached, so it leaves the `for` loop and runs the last line of the event handler. If `e.which` is not in `KEY`, the event handler returns `false` before the last line is reached.

Comment: Dang, apparently implementing this causes it to ignore EVERY key press (except the up arrow for some reason). Here is a JSFiddle of the code.
http://jsfiddle.net/DsNJb/

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. I removed `return false;` and replaced `break;` with `pingpong.pressedKeys[e.which].isDown = true;`

Answer (score 1):

`e.which` is IE only. Real browsers use `e.keyCode`

[jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Comment: jQuery normalizes the event object so `e.which` will work fine.