# HTML Form - Execute script when pressing 'Enter', without submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

OK, here's my situation *(I've solved this issue in the past, but since I'm not sure my approach was the best, I'm all ears for some advice)* :

- I've got a simple HTML form
- The purpose of this form is NOT to be submitted EVER
- The user normal clicks the (pseudo)`Submit` button, and the desired action is executed (via Javascript/Ajax, etc)

The thing is :

- If the user hits **enter**, then the form **is** submitted, something we definitely DON'T WANT.
- What we want is to *catch* that particular keypress, and in that case, trigger the action that would normally be executed if the button was clicked.

How would you go about this?

---

#### My Approach

---

**The Form**

```
<form id="someId" action="#" method="post" 
      onsubmit="return false;" onkeypress="return enterSub(this,event);">
...
</form>
```

**The Code**

```
function enterSub(inField, e) 
{ 
        var charCode;

        if(e && e.which)
        {
            charCode = e.which;
        }
        else if (window.event)
        {
            e = window.event;
            charCode = e.keyCode;
        }

        if (charCode == 13) 
        {
            performThatAction; // My Main action
        }
 }
```

Comment: [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind to the submit of the form rather than the click of a button, then prevent the default action.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("The action has occurred without submitting the form!");
});
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward and brilliantly efficient. Give me a minute and I'll let you know how it went... :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(){
  //do something
});
```

This function will trigger whenever user tries to submit the form (you will have to return false or prevent default)

Answer (score 2):

If you also would like to do something specific when users hit Enter, you could do something like:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
           e.preventDefault();
           // Do something         
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>
<script>
document.attachEvent("onkeydown", win_onkeydown_handler);
function win_onkeydown_handler()
{
alert(event.keyCode);
switch (event.keyCode){
case 13 : // 'enter'
event.returnValue = false;
event.keyCode = 0;
alert("Enter Blocked");// If need show this alert else comment it
break;

}
}
</script>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please use the above script to find enter key press u can handle the enter as u needed.Hope ur doubt as solved else please post me.