# Using .off() while it is nested inside of .on()

Tags: jquery, event-handling, listener, jquery-events

Is it possible to unbind a listener from within the listener? I want to do this because I have a listener which determines the criteria of its own unbinding (e.g. when a certain key is pressed, the listener should unbind).

```
$input.on("keydown.listenerOne", function (press) {  
   if(press=="37"){
      $input.off("keyup.listenerOne");
   }
});
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? Also I think `press` would be the event object not which key is pressed.

Comment: This is not a question, this will work if you change the `off("keyup....` to `off("keydown....`. And you change `press==` to `press.keyCode==`

Comment: It wasn't working due to the keydown/keyup inconsistency. I've been staring at my code for too long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work because you're binding on the `keydown` event and unbinding the `keyup` event, which has no binding per your example. Also the event you reference as `press` would be `e` or `event` and you'll need to reference the `which` property: `if(e.which == 37)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes that's a correct approach. You can unbind it inside the handler but be aware that you have two different events(keyup and keydown). Perhaps you meant keyup.

Answer (score 2):

You should be unbinding the same thing you are binding. In this case, you are attempting to unbind `keyup` when you hav `keydown` bound. Also, `press` will not tell you the keyCode, you should do

```
var code = press.keyCode || press.which;
if(code == 37) { //Enter keycode
   //Do something
}
```

rather than `if (press == "37")`

taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Comment: Cool, you can simplify even more by removing the ternary and replacing with `var code = press.keyCode || press.which;`

Comment: @AlienWebguy: You can just use `press.which` - jQuery normalises `which` for you so testing for `keyCode` is redundant.

Comment: Right that's what I used in my answer. I just wanted to mention how Jeff could simplify a ternary.

Comment: @nnnnnn I didn't realize jQuery normalized that. I will use it from now on. Thanks.