# How to fire alert once for each new space found in text String?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

I'm using below code to fire an alert every time a new space char is encountered as a user types into a text box.
This works until the user enters the first space, as the alert will be fired for each subsequent space.

For this String : 'test ' the alert will be fired once, which is correct

For this String : 'test test' the alert will be fired 5 times, but it should be just fired once.

For this String : 'test test test' the alert should be fired three times.

How can below code be amended so that alert fires just once for each new space character ?

```
$("#myDiv").keyup(function() {    
    if$("#myDiv").val().indexOf(' ') != -1)
    {
        alert("space found");
    }   ​
};
```

Comment: [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$("#myDiv").keyup(function() {

    var val = $(this).val(),
        len = val.length - 1;

    if (val[ len ] == ' ') {
        alert("space found");
    }

});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjYCK/)

Answer (score 4):

Pass the event object to the callback function, and test `e.which == 32` for keycode 32 (space)

```
// keyup callback receives the Event object e
$("#myDiv").keyup(function(e) {
    // When the key pressed was space, alert...
    if (e.which == 32)  {
        alert("space found");
    }   
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DL5pX/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by following code,

```
var x = false;
$(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      x = false;
    }
  }).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      x = true;
      alert('space pressed!!');
    }
  });
}
```