# Adjust TD height depending on textarea rows

Tags: jquery, textarea, html-table

I have a textarea with `rows="1"` inside a `<td>`, so it takes up as little space as possible when empty.

Now I was wondering, how would I best "expand" the textarea when the user presses the enter key?

I have put up a very simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdjsU/) to test the idea. Unfortunately I am not very good with jsfiddle, so I did not know how (or if) is it possible to use `.on()` or other event listeners, so I have simply put up a one-time update that runs when the jsfiddle is ran.

So far it works, but I was wondering if there's a better/more efficient way to do it.

PS to call the function I was thinking to use `keypress` and then this code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed) on SO

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
  //expand()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.expand').on('keypress', function (e) {

    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
        // Enter pressed... do anything here...
        var rows = $(this).attr('rows');
        var rowsNew = parseInt(rows) + 1;
        $(this).attr('rows', rowsNew);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdjsU/2/)