# ajax, javascript - start function with two events

Tags: javascript, ajax, events

I have one function and I need to start in on click or on pressing Enter key.
So I'd need something like:

```
<BUTTON onclick="searchProduct()" or onkeypress="searchProduct()">Hledat</BUTTON>
```

But only on pressing Enter. Not on any key.

Is this possible for Ajax or plain javascript?

OK, didn't expect that it is so complicated, so I give you whole of my code, because your answers are not working for my whole code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META charset="UTF-8" />
        <TITLE>Searchin engine</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <SCRIPT src="js_search.js"></SCRIPT>
        <FORM>
            <INPUT type="text" id="word" size="40" />
        </FORM>
         <BUTTON onclick="searchProduct(document.getElementById('word').value)">Hledat</BUTTON>
        <P id="display"></P>

    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keydown + keyup events for specific keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345870/keydown-keyup-events-for-specific-keys)

Comment: Most browsers probably perform onclick when you tab and enter

Comment: Button do not have key events

Comment: Assuming that you also have some kind of text input for your search term, you should make the text field react to Enter rather than the button

Answer (score 2):

Just add event listeners in your javascript (above your `searchProduct()` function, for instance)

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  searchProduct(document.getElementById('word').value);
})

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13) searchProduct(document.getElementById('word').value); // the keyCode 13 is equivalent to the enter key
})

function searchProduct(val) {
  alert(val);
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Hledat</button>
<input id="word" value="foo"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, it looks nice, but how to do this if I need to work with variable?

Comment: Work with variables in what way?

Comment: I need to take the value from INPUT with id "word" and get it in the function searchProduct(). But if it is no event in element BUTTON, I'm not able to do this.

Comment: @MichalVlasák I've changed my code to reflect what you want. That should work for you :)

Comment: Thank, but if I press Enter the page is reloading, maybe runs the script and the input is cleared and nothing else happens. I tried it in Firefox and also in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should have individual events on element and `enter`, you can either call specific function or you can trigger element's click.

If you wish enter and button click work same, I would suggest to trigger click event. This will make sure all UI states are updated and all processing are done. Reason for this is, we can add multiple handlers to a button for different processing and calling functions might not call other code.

```js
function keyPress(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById("btn").click();
  }
}

function notify() {
  console.log("Processing...")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="keyPress(event)">
<button id="btn" onclick="notify(event)">Notify</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<BUTTON onclick="searchProduct()"  onkeypress="searchProductKeyPress(event)">Hledat</BUTTON>

function searchProductKeyPress(event) {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        searchProduct();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function you can pass the event like this:

```
<BUTTON onclick="searchProduct(event)" onkeypress="searchProduct(event)">Hledat</BUTTON>
```

Now in the  function:

```
searchProduct(e){

    if(e.type === 'keypress' && e.keyCode !== 13){
        return;
    }    

    // put the code for search here.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

set id="btn_search_product" to your button

```
var btn_search_product = document.getElementById("btn_search_product");
btn_search_product.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        searchProduct(e);
    }
});
```

I actually use evento library https://github.com/petermichaux/evento

with it it would be:

```
evento.add(btn_search_product, "keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            searchProduct(e);
        }
});
```