# Perform Function on Key Press

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a site that displays images and forms from a database. Currently, I have links disguised as buttons that allows the user to switch to previous and next files.

```
$prev_key=$filenum.'_'.($fileindex-1);
$next_key=$filenum.'_'.($fileindex+1);

if(($fileindex-1)>=1)
  echo '<br>';
  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="view_file.php?k='.$prev_key.'" class="prevnext">Prev File</a>';  

if(($fileindex+1)<=$totalfilect)
  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="view_file.php?k='.$next_key.'" class="prevnext">Next File</a>';
```

This works well, but I also want the user to be able to switch files using the up (previous) and down (next) arrow keys. How could I either call the `$prev_key` and `$next_key` functions or have the key presses just activate the links with key presses?

Comment: just giv them same class  (prev button+prev arrow   and next button+next arrow) and use same event code

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345870/keydown-keyup-events-for-specific-keys

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of JavaScript-EventListener `onKeyPress` or `onKeyUp` - depending on your preferences or customer requirements.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

In the `JS-EventListener` code you have to call the respective url then. This is described in an other StackOverflow entry: https://stackoverflow.com/a/980721/3904215