# Using left and right arrow keys for additional navigation

Tags: jquery, events, keyboard

I want to add the ability for visitors to navigate between photo pages using their left and right arrow keys with cross-browser compatibility.

My existing HTML already has Back and Next links. What do I need to do to get the left key to trigger <%=previousLink%> and right key to trigger the <%=nextLink%>?

```
<div class="full-size-image-nav">
    <%if previousNumber <> 0 then%>
        <div class="previous">
            <p><a href="<%=previousLink%>">Back</a></p>
        </div>
    <%end if%>
    <%if nextNumber <> 0 then%>
        <div class="next">
            <p><a href="<%=nextLink%>">Next</a></p>
        </div>
    <%end if%>
</div>
```

I have seen [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed), but don't know how to adapt that to my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this one, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/qRqNf/1/

First click on result frame, then try to press left/right key.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
      if(e.which == 37) { // left     
          $(".previous a").trigger("click");
      }
      else if(e.which == 39) { // right     
          $(".next a").trigger("click");
      }
    });
    $(".previous a").on("click",function(){
        // your scripts for previous click here
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com';  
    });
    $(".next a").on("click",function(){
        // your scripts for next click here
        window.location = 'http://sg.yahoo.com/';   
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Your example works for bringing up an alert box, but how do I change the alerts into links? I tried replacing <a onclick="alert('Left arrow key');"> with <a onclick="http://www.google.com;"> and it didn't work.

Comment: alert is to see the action, for your script, remove onclick script, and leave your old working links, that will go previous and next....<a href="<%=previousLink%>">

Comment: check my update answer and test again, *it will not work in jsfiddle

Comment: Thank you! Your updated script works perfectly :-)
Hope this helps others.