# jQuery create and fire keypress event

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

how I can do to fire the `keypress` event to an `input` element?. The event is triggered but I can not make it run completely, because not write the letter.
I try the same recording the event, but I had the same problem.

```
<button>fire event</button>
<input id="test" />
<div id="info"></div>


$("#test").on('keypress', function(event){
    $('#info').append('<br />intro event: ' + event.keyCode);
});

$('button').on('click', function(event) {
    var e = $.Event('keypress', { keyCode: 102 } );
    $("#test").trigger( e );
});
```

[test](http://jsfiddle.net/dfcuS/)

Thank you.

**Edit**

I need is save all events that happen on my page and then able to fire. I have already complete the code to save the events, but my problem is how to fire.

Comment: Not sure I get it, are you trying to do [***THIS***](http://jsfiddle.net/gXfeQ/) ???

Comment: Here's some information that may come handy [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed?rq=1). It seems that depends on the browser as well.

Comment: ^^^ normalized in jQuery !