# Detect how a select was changed

Tags: jquery

I've got a select field that has logic on keyup, and change, to do stuff. Is there a way to check how it was changed?

For example: I only want the logic to be fired if it was changed by a mouse, or if enter was pressed on it.

**For those looking for my exact solution**

http://aaronscherer.me/blog/2013/07/31/jquery-roll-to-next-input/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can listen to any event on any element in the DOM.  Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4y7V/) as a starting point.  Here is a [full list of mouse events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) and [keyboard events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) you can listen for.

HTML

```
<select class="my-select-1">
    <option value="1">First</options>
    <option value="2">Second</options>
</select>

<select class="my-select-2">
    <option value="1">A choice</options>
    <option value="2">Another choice</options>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".my-select-1").on("click", function(event){
        alert('Do something - click event');
    });

    $('.my-select-2').on('keypress', function(e) {
         var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
         if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
            alert('Do something - enter key press');
         }    
    });

});
```

In the example above, `$(".my-select-1)` is the selector, it could be anything (an ID, a element type, etc).  More information on selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).  The next part, `.on("mousedown"` attaches an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements - in this case just a single event, `mousedown`.  More info about on [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

The second example, is a bit more fancy as we have to determine which key was pressed, but other than that uses the same concept.  You can find a very lengthy discussion about this on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed), but please note as of 1.7 `on` is the preferred method (not `bind`).

Comment: I swear, i thought click happened on the first click of the select... Well This pretty much solved my question, I'll be using this with possibly @undefined's answer, joining the two `on` statements into one

Comment: Yeah - I was just going to say if you gave an example of your code it would help us give you the best suggestion.  Depending on how you approach it @undefined method would work also - by placing a switch or if statements inside the function he suggests to have different behaviors for different events.

Comment: yeah, that's the idea. Thanks

Comment: Also, should probable mention, I'm using `click` instead of `mousedown`, as mousedown gets fired when you click on the select to get the list of options

Comment: I put my exact solution in the OP

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the *type* of the event, you can simply use the `type` property of the `event` object:

```
$('select').on('change keyup ...', function(event) {
   var type = event.type;
   // ...
});
```

Comment: Is there a defined list of `event.type` possibilities?

Comment: ah. Strange tho, they dont seem to mention aliases. eg. Blur actually has a type of `focusout`

Answer (score 0):

You could use onchange event, something like this :

```
$(document).on('change','#your_select',function() {
    //do something
})
```

Comment: OP wants to be able to respond to specific modes of change; I.e keyboard vs mouse. Rather than just responding to change entirely