# How to detect '@' using keydown or keyup jQuery event handlers?

Tags: jquery, keydown, keyup

What I need to do:
Detect when a user enters '@' in the textbox

What jQuery 'keyup' or 'keydown' events do:
It first detects a keyup/keydown when shift is pressed and another keyup/keydown when '2' is pressed. In order to make '@'.

How to make it identify a '@'?

Comment: Bind to `keypress` instead?

Comment: But came to know from another answer that "Keypress" works only in firefox?

Comment: Really? Where did you read that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed
Comment no.- 2

Comment: Ah, that comment is from 2009. Many things have changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

For browser which support DOM3 `event.key`,

```
textbox.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if(e.key === '@') alert('@ detected');
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jH6b7/1/)

Since `event.key` is not widely supported, you should have a `event.keyCode` or `event.which` fallback.

The problem is that those only contain the number of the key which produced the character, not the character itself. And in my keyboard, `@` doesn't have its own key, it must be produced with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`2` or `Alt Gr`+`2`.

Then, for keyboards like mine, you can use

```
textbox.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if(e.key === '@'
       ||
       e.altKey && e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode||e.which)===50
    ) 
        alert('@ detected');
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jH6b7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Txtbox").keyup (function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 50)
    {
        if (e.shiftKey === true)
        {
            alert ('@ was pressed' );
        }
        else
        {
            // do nothing
        }

    }
});
```

Please read this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.keyCode
Notes
In a keypress event, the Unicode value of the key pressed is stored in either the keyCode or charCode property, never both. If the key pressed generates a character (e.g. 'a'), charCode is set to the code of that character, respecting the letter case. (i.e. charCode takes into account whether the shift key is held down). Otherwise, the code of the pressed key is stored in keyCode.

keyCode is always set in the keydown and keyup events. In these cases, charCode is never set.

To get the code of the key regardless of whether it was stored in keyCode or charCode, query the which property.

Characters entered through an IME do not register through keyCode or charCode.