# Jquery on IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I am new to jquery as in new to try it get worked on IE and Firefox. My script works perfeclty without any trouble whatsoever on Safari, Chrome and Opera, but not on IE and Firefox.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here where I think is the problem: I store some strings in localStorage and use them in a fadeIn fadeOut animation. This works in the other browsers but not in FF (the animation is not run repeatedly). When I try just the animation without getting the strings from localStorage, it works in FF, this is why I suspect the problem in the localStorage.

```
var pro = localStorage.getItem("probes").split(",");
var teststim =  [
        {stim: pro[0],  type: "probe"},
        {stim: pro[1],  type: "probe"},
        {stim: pro[2],  type: "probe"}]
var displayWord = function() {
newword = teststim[Math.floor((Math.random() * teststim.length))];
$("#stimuli").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $("#stimuli").text(newword.stim).fadeIn(10);                    
});    
}
setInterval(displayWord, 2000);
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  clearInterval(timing);
  displayWord();
  setInterval(displayWord, 2000);
})
```

This basically takes values from localStorage, uses them in a fade animation, and runs this animation every 2000ms.

Any new ideas? Sorry for the unclear question at first.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? All I see is a simple html skeleton including jQuery lib.

Comment: It would be better if you can post the exact error message which you are getting!

Comment: jQuery 1.11.0 works for sure on IE and FF. Maybe clear your cache...

Comment: Don't use iso-8859-1 in the 21st century. We have had Unicode for a while now.

Comment: Did you put your jQuery code inside `document.ready`?

Comment: change your meta = `<meta charset="utf-8">`, please

Comment: @Niklas `My script works perfeclty without any trouble whatsoever on Safari, Chrome and Opera, but not on IE and Firefox.`  It's nothing to do with document.ready

Comment: @Archer - This is like trying to fix your car by showing us a picture of it. We need the actual code to help you further.

Comment: @Niklas Yes, definitely.  It could be something as tiny as a trailing comma in an object declaration.  No way to know till we see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. In my case this helped and fixed my problem.

1. I changed all localStorage to window.localStorage

   window.localStorage.getItem("probes").split(",");
2. I adjusted a keypress event I have used so that the actual key is coded both in the e.which and e.keyCode way.

   var code = e.keyCode || e.which; (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed))

Maybe someone with the same problem can make use of this.

Answer (score -1):

> Does it have to do with how I call jquery?

To answer your question, from the HTML snippet you posted it doesn't seem to have anything to do with that.

jQuery 1.x.x supports IE till older version.

Note: using `UTF-8` is recommended over using the `latin` charset.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

or the shorter HTML5 version

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Also, try forcing the latest browser version:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```