# Adding square brackets to either side of the text on an input form with a onkeyup event?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, input, inline

I want square brackets to automatically appear on either side of a string of text when entered in the text field of an input form. The result needs to coincide with an onkeyup event.

Here's a snippet of code from the .php file:

```
$generator .= '<div class="plugin_input_wrapper">';
$generator .= 'Enter your text:';
$generator .= '<input class="text-box" type="text" id="plugin_bottom_text" maxlength="25" name="plugin_bottom_text" onkeyup="plugin_text_type();">';
$generator .= '<span class="text">&nbsp Font size:</span><input class="text-box2" type="text" id="plugin_text_font_size" maxlength="2">&nbsp px</div>';
```

Is this possible to do with inline Javascript?

Comment: yes, it's possible, but it'd probably confuse users when text they didn't type suddenly shows up int he box. why not do `[<input .. />]` and then add the `[]` to the entered text afterwards?

Comment: Be careful with this, because you may get a *not so nice surprise* from PHP later on, as that POST variable may come out as `[variable]`. This could have adverse effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uses jQuery as a quick hack and very mucky but this is a simple way to do it:

```
$('.plugin_input_wrapper input').on('keyup', function() {
  var oldVal = $(this).val().replace(/\[/g,'');
  oldVal = oldVal.replace(/\]/g,'');
  var val = '[' + oldVal + ']';

  $(this).val(val);
});
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gaxewatu/10/edit?html,js,output)

Simply gets the current value of the textbox being typed in, trims out the old brackets and adds them in again and injects back into the textbox

Comment: As long as the class names defined above are the same then I see no reason why it would make a difference if PHP is involved. This is just a bit of jQuery that you could add to the page in a $(document).ready(function() { // Code }); snippet

Comment: The class is also used elsewhere in the code. Can that be written inline and attached to the current onkeyup event?

Comment: Yes, you could write it inline, everything in between the $('.plugin_input_wrapper input').on('keyup', function() { // Here });

Comment: I tried adding that after: onkeyup="plugin_text_type(); and it didn't work.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gaxewatu/22/edit?html,js,output there's the new code. You use the function test() and then add onkeyup="test()" to the input you want to carry this method on.

Comment: Where do I put the script tag in the php file?

Comment: If you're using pure PHP then echo it out  after the output you need it attaching to is. E.g. $generator .= '<script>function add_brackets(obj) { // code here }</script>'; Being careful about your quotes  etc

Comment: I'm getting an error with this line: oldVal = oldVal.replace(/\]/g,'this.value + \']\';'); unexpected '');' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: I got this to work like this: <script type="text/javascript">function test(obj) {
  var oldVal = obj.val().replace(/\[/g,\'\');
  oldVal = oldVal.replace(/\]/g,\'\');
  var val = \'[\' + oldVal + \']\';
  obj.val(val);
}
</script> Unfortunately when I write to the canvas it leaves a character out on the end.

Comment: The script writes properly to canvas as an oninput event, except I've lost the ability to backspace, can that be fixed?

Comment: That'd be the hacky nature of this solution. As it runs it on every keypress it adds the bracket. You could add in some functionality which checks the keycode being pressed, and if it was a backspace, not run the code.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed you can see here how to do it. Backspace is code 8

Comment: Sorry can't keep giving you the whole answer, you'll work it out if you do the reading :)

Comment: Couldn't figure it out, neither could anybody else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310701/enable-backspace-with-jquery-oninput-event-within-the-text-on-an-input-form/25311462#25311462

Answer (score 2):

It would be very confusing for users if this is done while the user is typing. One approach to make it less surprising would be to add the brackets once the focus has been lost (on blur). Here is a snippet:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" onblur="this.value = '[' + this.value + ']'"/>
</form>
```

And here is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZwRL/1/

EDIT: The PHP would look like this:

```
$generator .= '<form>'
$generator .= '<input type="text" onblur="this.value = \'[\' + this.value + \']\'"/>'
$generator .= '</form>'
```

Comment: This seems like a viable solution, but it breaks my installation. Is there a different variation of this?

Comment: @jay I'm not sure why that would break anything since it is standard JS. What's the error?

Comment: @Jay Is the string quoted and escaped? I've updated my original response to include the PHP code.

Comment: With what I'm trying to do, it looks like i'll have to use the onkeyup event, but it returns [a][b][c], instead of [abc]

Comment: @Jay you'll have to update your original question to include the details if the problem.

Comment: Updated. Is this even possible?