# Enable Backspace with jQuery oninput event within the text on an input form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input, backspace

I have an input form that has a jQuery event applied to it that creates square brackets around the users input. The issue is that the event prevents the ability to use backspace to delete the text. I'm looking for a way to check if backspace is being pressed and prevent the code from runnning.

jQuery Script

```
function test(obj) {
var oldVal = obj.val().replace(/\[/g,\'\');
oldVal = oldVal.replace(/\]/g,\'\');
var val = \'[\' + oldVal + \']\';
obj.val(val);
```

Input Form

```
oninput="test($(this));"
```

Comment: `test($(this))`? I think `$(this)` is undefined there. Can you not just do `if (e.which == 8) return false` (8 being backspace)

Comment: it makes it easier to answer questions like this if you add a jsfiddle to your question. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Heres a jsfiddle that needs to be slightly modified: http://jsbin.com/gaxewatu/22/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

```
 function test(obj,e) {  
      if(!(e.which == 8)){
           var oldVal = obj.val().replace(/\[/g,'');
           oldVal = oldVal.replace(/\]/g,'');
           var val = '[' + oldVal + ']';
           obj.val(val);
      }
 }
```

and pass event as parameter  ..

```
 <input class="text-box" onkeyup="test($(this),event)">
```

Comment: Which function @Jay??

Comment: obj   the one that adds the brackets.