# Jquery ajax perform only on certain keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I made a script that sends information from the input to a script whenever a keyup happens. The problem is that it sends a request whenever any key is pressed(obviously). This means that some requests, when for instance arrow keys are pressed, are done for nothing. Is there a way to remove such requests or it doesn't matter if they happen?

```
$('input[name="rusername"]').on("focus keyup", function() {

    // if ($(this).val() === '') $('#rusererr').html('Enter your desired username; between 8 and 32 characters');

    var username = $(this).val();

    $.post("register.php", {
        rusername: username
    }, function(stuff) {
        //daca nu sunt erori
        if (stuff==='1') alert(stuff);
        else alert(stuff);
    });
});
```

Comment: simply enclose the `post` call in a condition which filters the desired keycodes - or better - do the call after the input field lost focus (which is most likely a good sign, that the user achieved their desired result).

Comment: Closely related to [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed) (that's for `keypress` instead of `keyup`, though; I'm not sure their normalized behavior is 100% the same, though)

Comment: For performance reasons you absolutely *should not* send and ajax request on the keyup event - use a more generic event instead.

Comment: Which one? I could use blur, but if I'd be to match two password fields, they wouldn't match until the user leaves the second field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the keycodes:

```
$('input[name="rusername"]').on("focus keyup", function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which;
    if (keyCode != 13) {
        //AJAX
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```

I used `13` as an example, you'll have to lookup which keycodes you want to exclude.

Comment: I see. Thought there might be some functionality that excludes it automatically.

Comment: Nope... `keyup` does exactly that, fires on any key up :D. You can always make an array of bad keycodes and check the index of the current keycode against that array.

Answer (score 0):

Check the keycode for some of the key.

- Enter: 13
- Up: 38
- Down: 40
- Right: 39
- Left: 37
- Esc: 27
- SpaceBar: 32
- Ctrl: 17
- Alt: 18
- Shift: 16

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var exclude = [37, 38, 39, 40] // arrow keys, you can add more. 
$('input[name="rusername"]').on("focus keyup", function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (exclude.indexOf(keyCode) == -1) {
        // do ajax here
    } else { return; }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to send an ajax request on every key action?

Sending an ajax request only on the blur event of the input greatly reduces the number of AJAX calls and does not need to mess around with keycodes (keycodes are a very tough topic!). And if you absolutely have to, save the results in between in `localStorage` where it does not matter that much if you do some nonsense save operations.

```js
$("#input").on("blur",function(){
  $("#result").html("An Ajax call would be triggered now!");
});

$("#input").on("keyup",function(){
  $("#result").html("The following string will be save locally: "+this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text">
<br><br>
<div id="result">
  
  </div>
```