# JQuery changing CSS in for loop with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

My question is: what is the most intelligent way to use a for loop which affects CSS via jQuery and a timer together?

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j6jLh2dn/

Below is my attempt at implementing a timer which defines a certain amount of time that you can either press the enter key, or not press the enter key, and depending on the situation, it will push a value to an array.

```
setTimeout(function(){
            if(e.which == 13){
                choice = 1;
            } else {
                choice = 0;
            }

            if(nBack == randomNumber){
                if(choice == 1){
                    correct.push(0);
                } else if(choice == 0){
                    incorrect.push(0);
                }
            } else {
                if(choice == 0){
                    correct.push(0);
                } else if(choice == 1){
                    incorrect.push(0);
                }
            }

        }, 1000 * i * y)();
```

and here's the portion which should select a certain css id, then edit it based on a random number being chosen:

```
randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * (m+1) );

            while(randomNumber === history[i-1]){
                randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * (m+1) );
            }

            $("." + randomNumber).css({ "background-color": "#ffe"});

            history[i] = randomNumber;
```

I have gotten it running without the timer with just alerts, and I have also gotten the timer to work, but upon trying to integrate the two and have it affect CSS, it won't work.

Comment: Where does the `e` come from? A timer is not an event handler. If you'll take a look at the console, there's an error message: `ReferenceError: e is not defined.`

Comment: if you mean e.which, that's just for the enter key being pressed

Comment: It is not, `which` is a property of `event`, which is passed to event handlers, not timed functions.

Comment: What do you suggest I do? I got the idea to do that from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed

Comment: To detect key presses, you've to [attach an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), like `keydown` or `keypress` to `window` for example. It's not clear to me, what you actually want to achieve, but an event listener is something to start from, when ever you want to detect key presses.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the code

```
 $("." + randomNumber).css({ "background-color": "#ffe"});
```

with

```
  $("." + randomNumber).css({ "backgroundColor": "#ffe"});
```

jQuery does not accept "-" when entering css property via object

Comment: I'll take note of that, thanks. Unfortunately, that didn't help this case :(