# Event key code 13 simulation not working

Tags: backbone.js, mocha.js, keypress, sinon

I'm writing tests for a Backbone view where I simulate a key press event by creating `$.Event("keypress", { which: 13 })` and passing it into the `trigger` method in my test suit. However when I look at my test results, I see that in my `createOnEnter` function, this returns on the first condition and the tests fail with the following message `AssertionError: expected addCommentToCollection to have been called at least once, but it was never called`, meaning that it is not recognising the key press event as 13.

Why is this happening? 
Is my set-up incorrect?

This is the backbone function I am trying to test:

```
createOnEnter: function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode != 13) return;
        if (!this._input.val()) return;

        this.addCommentToCollection();
        this.resetInputField();
        this.concealButtons();
    }
```

This is triggered in the `backbone` eventhash which listens to keypress event on the input field.

The necessary test set-up for this question (there are many other stubs and spies):

```
describe("AppView", function() {

    before(function () {

        // create test fixture
        this.$fixture = $('<div id="app-view-fixture">' +
        '<input id="new-comment" type="text" placeholder="what do you think?">' +
        '<div class="comment-buttons">' +
        '<div class="post-button"></div>' +
        '<div class="cancel-button"></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<section id="main" class="comment-list">' +
        '<ul class="comments-container" id="comment-list"></ul>' +
        '</section></div>');

    });

    beforeEach(function () {

        // bind the fixture for each run
        this.$fixture.appendTo($("#fixtures"));

        // instantiate our models
        this.model1 = new Comment({
            "comment": "I like cookies",
            "created": "12-12-2012",
            "modified": "13-01-2013",
            "user": {
                "username": "Mr. Knight"
            }
        });

        this.model2 = new Comment({
            "comment": "I pirate everything!",
            "created": "14-09-2012",
            "modified": "21-01-2013",
            "user": {
                "username": "Mr. Casanova"
            }
        });

        // place models in array for use in collection instantiation
        this.models = [this.model1, this.model2];

        // instantiate our collection with models from above
        this.collection = new CommentList(this.models,
            {url: "items/1234567890/comments"}
        );

        this.addCommentSpy = sinon.spy(AppView.prototype, "addCommentToCollection");

        this.createEnterSpy = sinon.spy(AppView.prototype, "createOnEnter");

        this.resetSpy = sinon.spy(AppView.prototype, "resetInputField");

        this.concealSpy = sinon.spy(AppView.prototype, "concealButtons");

        // instantiate our new view
        this.view = new AppView ({
            "collection": this.collection,
            "el": this.$fixture
        });

    });

    afterEach(function () {

        this.addCommentSpy.restore();

        this.resetSpy.restore();

        this.concealSpy.restore();

        this.createEnterSpy.restore();


        // undo our server
        this.server.restore();

        // destroy our view
        this.view.remove();
    });

    after(function () {
        // empty our fixtures div
        $("#fixtures").empty();
    });

it("should trigger createOnEnter when keypress - 'Enter' - with value in input field", function () {

        this.view.$("#new-comment").val("Cousin Benson, it is broken!");

        this.view.$("#new-comment").trigger($.Event("keypress", { which: 13 }));

        expect(this.createEnterSpy).to.have.been.called;
        expect(this.addCommentSpy).to.have.been.called;
        expect(this.resetSpy).to.have.been.called;
        expect(this.concealSpy).to.have.been.called;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

**Event Properties**

jQuery normalizes the following properties for cross-browser consistency:

`target`
`relatedTarget`
`pageX`
`pageY`
`which`
`metaKey`

So use `event.which` or

```
var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
    //Do something
}
```

like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)