# How to restrict dot operator('.') in mobile browser using Javascript/ JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am working on a mobile web application where I need to use a text box which is of type "Number".

```html
<input type="number" name="Mileage" id="txtExample" onkeypress="javascript:return validateNumbers(event,'txtExample');"/>
```

The problem am getting is here I need to restrict the dot (`.`) from being entered in to text box and the javascript method I have written for this is:

```
function validateNumbers(evt, txtField) {            
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    else if (charCode == 8)
        return true;            
    }
```

The charcode of `.` is 46 but its going in to `true` every time. The strange thing is in desktop website this code is working fine but when running in mobile browser (Chrome, IE) it's not working.

I need assistance guys. This approach don't work in Mobile browser. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use the min attribute so you don't have this problem?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979619/how-to-get-keycodes-from-android-mobile-device-keyboard

Comment: You ask question about: `How to restrict dot operator('.')`. But isn't your question just `How to restrict only integer in input type number`???  If so, google it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example

```
$("#txtExample").on("keypress",function(evt){
    var keycode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
      if (keycode  == 46) {
        return false;
      }
});
```

Comment: This code is restricting the dot in the input field. Nothing more nothing less. Look at his question. 
How to restrict dot operator('.') in mobile browser using Javascript/ JQuery

Comment: @Rick Bronger, Yeah i used the same code but its not returning false once i run it in mobile browser. Simply, i should allow only 0 to 9 numbers to be entered by User.

Comment: When i press dot in text box , am unable to catch the key code its coming blank may be because if input type="number" ? its working when i give as type="text". I Want this to work in "Number type".

Comment: @ Rick Bronger, thanks for posting fiddle example but i know its working in desktop browser just open the same http://jsfiddle.net/8nz11auz/4/ link in mobile using any browser and just see, my concern is that. Could you please post any suggestion how i can achieve that in mobile browser.