# Check on keycode return undefined

Tags: jquery

The code below is supposed to click a `button` when the Enter key is pressed and empty another `textbox` if any other key is clicked.

I'm unable to check the `keycode` as `keycode` is always `undefined`.

```
$('#txtSearch').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keycode != 13)
        $('#txtId').val("");
    else
        $('#BtnGo').click();
})
```

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: You have to try `e.which`

Comment: Note it's `keyCode` - case sensitivity. Also you should probably use `e.which` for full cross browser support: `if ((e.which || e.keyCode) != 13)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan should not matter when jQuery normalizes it

Comment: @epascarello true, just covering all bases.

Comment: @closevoter, would you please tell me why it's not a programming question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, the keyCode property does not work on the onkeypress event (will only return 0). For a cross-browser solution, use the which property together with keyCode, e.g:

```
var x = event.which || event.keyCode;  // Use either which or keyCode, depending on browser support
```

So use following code

```
$('#txtSearch').keyup(function (event) {
    var x = event.which || event.keyCode;  // Use either which or keyCode, depending on browser support

        if (x!= 13)
            $('#txtId').val("");
        else
            $('#BtnGo').click();
    })
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do this

```
$('#txtSearch').keyup(function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code != 13)
        $('#txtId').val("");

   else
        $('#BtnGo').click();
})
```