# What do I need to create a website similar to this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keylistener, keyevent

I want to make a website similar to http://www.lidogotlights.com but I just can't seem to figure out the code to bring up an image to your screen when a key is pressed. I was able to open up the page source of the website, and it's basically just GIFs triggered on a pressed key. I seem to be just going in circles with my searches, I'm pretty sure that i need a KeyListener, I just don't know how to start. And that I might have to preload the images or hide them?

Also, is this possible with just javascript?

*P.S. I'm still very new coding so this doesn't need to be perfect,I just want to figure out how to perform the key events function.

Comment: the website uses react,typescript & google web analytics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to add an event-listener to the window like:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.charCode == "97") {
        alert("The 'a' key is pressed.");
    }
}
```

In place of the alert you can change the background image to the required gif.

[EDIT]
Also I noticed upon pressing a key without lifting causes some weird behavior.
To solve that a pause can be used inside the function like:

```
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
        if (e.charCode == "97") {
            //Change background gif
            var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            miliseconds = //length of gif
            while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
            }
            //Change background gif to default
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! But what should I replace the alert with? I tried: this.src = "MY IMAGE"; and it didn't work

Comment: You need to have a `div` covering the area and change the image.