# How to catch keyboard input with jQuery .keyup() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input, keyup

Working on a simple hangman game, and I'm trying to catch the user input with the `keyup()`, but when I log it to the console I'm realizing something isn't working right... this is my code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

    userInput = e.value;
    console.log(userInput);

});
```

I also tried doing this, but it isn't working either.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

    userInput = $(this).val();
    console.log(userInput);

});
```

oh, by the way, **userInput is a global variable.**

Comment: you tried to debug it ???. what you get in `e` ?

Comment: e.which? try it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed

Comment: when I use e.value I get undefined back. when I do $(this).val(), I get a blank space back. e.which gives me the ASCII code, but not the actual letter...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to get the `value` from `target` property of the event. Try the following way:

```js
$('#txtInput').on('keyup', function(e) {

    var userInput = e.target.value;
    console.log(userInput);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input: <input type='text' id="txtInput"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
$( "#whichkey" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( event.type + ": " +  event.which );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="whichkey" placeholder="type something">
<div id="log"></div>
```

Use [event.which](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

> Description: For key or mouse events, this property indicates the specific key or button that was pressed.

Comment: hey, thanks... I completely forgot to say that I'm trying to display the letter instead of the ASCII value...

Comment: print its `.val()`

Comment: like this...? $(this).val()?