# Why i cant read the value with _POST, but i can check isset with _POST (and it works)

Tags: php

So what i would like to achive  its a simple suggestion with AJAX, everithing works fine, but it wont read the value of the input with POST... i can verifiy if isset, the index is working... but i cant even _POST the input...

the JQ post method for ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").keyup(function(){
        var name = $("input").val();
        $.post("suggestions.php", {
            suggestion: name


        }, function(data, status){
            $("#test").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

the input name and   #test paraghaph are there , and they work

suggestions.php :

```
$existingNames = array("Daniel","Dennis", "Alex");

if (isset($_POST['suggestion']))
{
    $name = $_POST['suggestion'];
            //$name = "D" ( if i uncomment this it will show Daniel and Denis)

    foreach ($existingNames as $exista) {
        if(strpos($exista , $name) !== false){
            echo $exista;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried doing either `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` to see what is in the POST array? Also, unless your search will involve sensitive / long data, most people simply use GET requests for searches

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the `$.post("suggestions.php", {` line and checked what `name` is being set to.

Comment: This Q&A [might be worth reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801424/how-to-catch-keyboard-input-with-jquery-keyup-function)

Comment: So,  in JQ if u use # ( id selector) , the code works, i dont really understand why is that .

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's set, doesn't mean it's not `empty`

```
if (isset($_POST['suggestion'] && ! empty($_POST['suggestion'])) {
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: Hi, this really is just a comment.

Comment: you are right , but it is not emtpy, in JQ if u use # ( id selector) , the code works :| can you tell me how should i take down the question... i feel embarased.