# When pressing Enter, text box goes down a line instead of calling function

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, datatables

I'm trying to set a messaging website (school purposes).
What I want to happen is that when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> the text in the textbox will be sent to a PHP page called `InsertMessage.php` and `DisplayMessages.php` and the text box to be set to "".
Instead, When I press enter the text box will only go down a line.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#ChatText").keyup(function(e) {
    //when we press enter
    if (e.keycode == 13) {
      var ChatText = $("#ChatText").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'InsertMessage.php',
        data: {
          ChatText: ChatText
        },
        success: function() {
          $("$ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php");#
          ("ChatText").val("");
        }
      });
    }
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    $("#ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php");
  }, 1500);

  $("#ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php");
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ChatBig">
  <div id="ChatMessages" class="scrollbar">
  </div>
  <textarea id="ChatText" name="ChatText" placeholder="Type Message..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a response using [jQuery Event Keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Comment: improved formatting and added code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you check for the key it needs to be e.keyCode instead of e.keycode
also there are many other typos

```
  $("$ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php");
  #("ChatText").val("");
```

for example shoud be:

```
  $("ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php");
  $("ChatText").val("");
```

there might be some more so check your syntax

Working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ChatText").keyup(function(e){
        //when we press enter
        if(e.keyCode === 13)
        {
            var ChatText= $("#ChatText").val();
            $("#ChatText").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ChatMessages" class="scrollbar">
    <textarea id="ChatText" name="ChatText" placeholder="Type Message..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed some of these, but it still does'nt work :( Am new to this and Im using notepad++ because studio code annoyed me. Now trying VS. I need it really fast if you can help me :)

Comment: Do you know how to open the console in your browser?
this will help you finding the errors if notepad++ is not highlighting them.

I would suggest you to use an IDE for that but I don't know any good and free IDE for web development.

Comment: Opened the console, am looking for an IDE right now.. What do I do with the console?

Comment: The console should print errors that are caused by your script if you load your script in the browser.

Comment: It doesnt print anything :( Anyways I just downloaded PHPStorm

Comment: PHPStorm is good this will help a lot. Hmm i'll edit my answer and add the code snippet i tested it with and then you can build your code around it

Comment: but the snippet works?
then the problem need to be elsewhere maybe its a problem with your php. I don't know. The text in your code only gets reset when the ajax call to the php was successfull so maybe thats not the case.

Comment: Ah I forgot to delete my part haha

Comment: And the response is stored inside vat CharText right?

Comment: whatever was in the textarea before enter was pressed will be stored in var CharText (also when the textarea is empty for example)

Comment: Now, if I have problems with my ajax call, where should I look?

Comment: below success:function()... you can add ``error:function(xhr, status, err) {console.log(xhr.responseText)}`` or something like this to get more information why the request fails or if it fails

Comment: After many many many trial and error I found that the problem is with this:
``` $("#ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php"); ```
syntax

Comment: can't help you with that, I'm not very experienced with php. I'd use nodejs for something like this